# How to intercept Grpc responses sent by a GrpcServer

Tags: interceptor, grpc-java

I am new to Grpc world.
As of now I know that I can intercept Requests received by a server by implementing ServerInterceptor interface.

How to intercept the response generated by the server?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a complete example of how to use server interceptors here:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/header

The example shows how to add custom headers by intercepting the `sendHeaders` method. Since you are interested in the response generated by the server, you can instead `@Override` the [sendMessage method](https://grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerCall.html#sendMessage-RespT-).